# Handling routing errors with angular/ui-router and nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am building an app with angularjs using ui-router and my API is handled by an express server with nodejs.

I'm trying to handle properly the server errors such as 404 and 500 errors.
The way I do it know is the following:

```
  // handling 404 errors
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.status !== 404)
      return next(err);

    res.status(404)
    res.render('index', { status: '404' })
  });
```

And then I catch the route on the server side with ui-router:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/error');
```

This works fine for 404 and I do the same for 500 error. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the error status code.

On can I catch the status sent by the server with ui-router or without making an extra http request?